# big commerce authorize.net CIM implementation

Tags: bigcommerce, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

Currently working on writing some software to create a backorder for our new store, but the current big commerce checkout is using the authorize.net AIM system.  Does anyone know how to setup the CIM for authorize.net on big commerce?

Answer (score 0):

Requirements

- Your store must be on a Plus plan or higher.
- Your store needs to be using Optimized One-Page Checkout.

Follow the instructions here:

[BigCommerce: Enabling Stored Credit Cards](https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Enabling-Stored-Credit-Cards)

> In order to use Authorize.net for stored credit cards, merchants will need to 
>   sign up for the Customer Information Manager in the Authorize.net Dashboard. To
>   learn more, see What is the Customer Information Manager (CIM).

More information here:

[Authorize.Net: What is the Customer Information Manager (CIM)](https://support.authorize.net/s/article/What-Is-the-Customer-Information-Manager-CIM)